# Encode frames to MP4 Video in rust

Tags: rust, video, video-processing

I need to convert video frames (&[u8]) to an MP4 video. I've been looking at the `ffav-rs` crate but I can't really figure out how to use it. Can anybody help me with this?

I've tried using most FFMPEG crates but literally none of them compiled just giving me an error with no further detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.